# resignFirstResponder does not dismiss keyboard

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

I have a UITextField and a UIButton. If the button is tapped while the text field is active, I want to dismiss the keyboard, but I'm unable to do so. I tried calling [textField resignFirstResponder] and [textField endEditing:YES] when the button is tapped, but they have no effect -- [textField isFirstResponder] returns false, so it's not surprising that resignFirstResponder has no effect. But in that case, why isn't the keyboard disappearing? Thanks.

Comment: Also, if I push a view while the keyboard is active, the keyboard is shown again when the view is popped. Does UIKit remember which view is the first responder and restore the first responder status to that view when its view controller is shown?

Comment: Finally, is there a clean way to have the keyboard disappear if the user taps or swipes elsewhere? Something like disableKeyboardOnFocusLoss would be ideal :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your "textField" class member is properly hooked up in the nib file.  NSLog it's value right before you call firstResponder and see if it's nil.    Also, enter text into the textfield and see that you can properly print it out with NSLog at the same point you're calling resignFirstResponder.   Usually when a control does not respond correctly it's because IBOutlets aren't hooked up properly.

Comment: Ah, the IBOutlet wasn't linked in IB. Thanks, and sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Is there a way to configure the UITextField so that it dismisses the keyboard on *any* touch or swipe on any other view in the window?

Comment: Not a waste at all, the more questions/answers people see like this, the more and the sooner the "Check the Outlets!" thought arises, the sooner problems are fixed.

Comment: I think you need to add code in all other views to dismiss the keyboard if it's up.   If you have more than one UITextField then cache the currently active one in a data member in your class like "UITextField *currentTF", and then just call [self.currentTF resignFirstResponder]" when any other view gets some activity.

Answer (score 0):

have you added `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in your .H ??

Comment: Well, I defined an IBAction that is hooked up in IB to the Return key. Since all the methods of the delegate are optional, and by default textFieldShouldEndEditing is assumed to return true, I don't see why I need the delegate. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a bad answer. Omitting to add a delegate to a class definition in a .h file will lead to a compile error in case you do something like: self.delegate = self .

Answer (score 0):

Try making an IBAction

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And connect it to the UIButton

Comment: But the user may not have pressed return! Why should the "auto enable return key" matter? I want the keyboard to go away if the user taps the button while the text field is active -- I don't care about the return key. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the connection turned out to be missing. Silly me. Thanks for your help!